# What are the CloudWatch Logs API v2 equivalents of these three V1 classes: AWSLogs, AWSLogsClientBuilder, PutLogEventsResult?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I decided to just cold-turkey update my Cloudwatch Logs from v1.x to v2.x (latest) in the POM, then go into the code that uses it and hit `Ctrl+Shift+O` ("Reorganize Imports") in Eclipse.

The result was actually not bad with just three classes not found:

[image]

i.e.

```
AWSLogs
AWSLogsClientBuilder
PutLogEventsResult
```

What are the replacements or closest equivalents to these classes in V2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- AWSLogs -> [CloudWatchLogsClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudwatchlogs/CloudWatchLogsClient.html)
- AWSLogsClientBuilder -> [CloudWatchLogsClientBuilder](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudwatchlogs/CloudWatchLogsClientBuilder.html)
- PutLogsEventResult -> [PutLogEventsResponse](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudwatchlogs/model/PutLogEventsResponse.html)